# xymatrix figures cause compilation error

Tags: xy-pic, xymatrix

I formatted my computer, and installed LYX (latest version 2.3.3).
I have a lyx file which won't compile (it compiled before formating my computer) for some reason. I realized that after deleting all xymatrix figures it does compile. The error  that I recieve is as follows:

[image: The Error:]

I would really appreciate if someone can help me solve this.
I don't know if it would be helpful, but the following is the complete log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.11.5)  6 NOV 2019 21:18
entering extended mode
**./Exam_Prep_Notes.tex
(Exam_Prep_Notes.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>


("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\articl
e.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10
.clo"
File: size10.clo 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fonten
c.sty"
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\t1enc.
def"
File: t1enc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inpute
nc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\latin9
.def"
File: latin9.def 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
))
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\co
lor.sty"
Package: color 2016/07/10 v1.1e Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cf
g\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 147.

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-de
f\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\bab
el.sty"
Package: babel 2019/09/27 3.34 The Babel package

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\swi
tch.def"
File: switch.def 2019/09/27 3.34 Babel switching mechanism
)
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/arabi\bblop
ts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-engli
sh\english.ldf"
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\bab
el.def"
File: babel.def 2019/09/27 3.34 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen103

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\txt
babel.def")
\bbl@dirlevel=\count89
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
))
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\ams
text.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\ams
gen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen104
))
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xy.
sty"
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xy.
tex" Bootstrap'ing: catcodes, docmode,
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyr
ecat.tex")
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyi
dioms.tex")

 Xy-pic version 3.8.9 <2013/10/06>
 Copyright (c) 1991-2013 by Kristoffer H. Rose <krisrose@tug.org> and others
 Xy-pic is free software: see the User's Guide for details.

Loading kernel: messages; fonts; allocations: state,
\X@c=\dimen105
\Y@c=\dimen106
\U@c=\dimen107
\D@c=\dimen108
\L@c=\dimen109
\R@c=\dimen110
\Edge@c=\toks17
\X@p=\dimen111
\Y@p=\dimen112
\U@p=\dimen113
\D@p=\dimen114
\L@p=\dimen115
\R@p=\dimen116
\Edge@p=\toks18
\X@origin=\dimen117
\Y@origin=\dimen118
\X@xbase=\dimen119
\Y@xbase=\dimen120
\X@ybase=\dimen121
\Y@ybase=\dimen122
\X@min=\dimen123
\Y@min=\dimen124
\X@max=\dimen125
\Y@max=\dimen126
\lastobjectbox@=\box27
\zerodotbox@=\box28
\almostz@=\dimen127
direction,
\d@X=\dimen128
\d@Y=\dimen129
\K@=\count90
\KK@=\count91
\Direction=\count92
\K@dXdY=\dimen130
\K@dYdX=\dimen131
\xyread@=\read1
\xywrite@=\write3
\csp@=\count93
\quotPTK@=\dimen132
utility macros; pictures: \xy, positions,
\swaptoks@@=\toks19
\connectobjectbox@@=\box29
objects,
\styletoks@=\toks20
decorations; kernel objects: directionals, circles, text; options; algorithms: 
directions, edges, connections;  Xy-pic loaded)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifp
df.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ift
ex.sty"
Package: iftex 2019/10/24 v1.0a TeX engine tests
))
Package: xy 2013/10/06 Xy-pic version 3.8.9

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xya
ll.tex"  Xy-pic option: All features v.3.8
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyc
urve.tex"  Xy-pic option: Curve and Spline extension v.3.12 curve,
\crv@cnt@=\count94
\crvpts@=\toks21
\splinebox@=\box30
\splineval@=\dimen133
\splinedepth@=\dimen134
\splinetol@=\dimen135
\splinelength@=\dimen136
circles,
\L@=\dimen137
loaded)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyf
rame.tex"  Xy-pic option: Frame and Bracket extension v.3.14 loaded)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyc
mtip.tex"  Xy-pic option: Computer Modern tip extension v.3.7
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyt
ips.tex"  Xy-pic option: More Tips extension v.3.11 loaded) loaded)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyl
ine.tex"  Xy-pic option: Line styles extension v.3.10
\xylinethick@=\dimen138
loaded)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyr
otate.tex"  Xy-pic option: Rotate and Scale extension v.3.8 loaded)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyc
olor.tex"  Xy-pic option: Colour extension v.3.11 loaded)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xym
atrix.tex"  Xy-pic option: Matrix feature v.3.14
\Row=\count95
\Col=\count96
\queue@=\toks22
\queue@@=\toks23
\qcount@=\count97
\qcount@@=\count98
\matrixsize@=\count99
loaded)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xya
rrow.tex"  Xy-pic option: Arrow and Path feature v.3.9 path, \ar, loaded)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyg
raph.tex"  Xy-pic option: Graph feature v.3.11 loaded) loaded)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyp
df.tex"  Xy-pic option: PDF driver v.1.7 Xy-pic pdf driver: `color' extension s
upport
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyp
df-co.tex" loaded) Xy-pic pdf driver: `curve' extension support
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyp
df-cu.tex" loaded) Xy-pic pdf driver: `frame' extension support
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyp
df-fr.tex" loaded) Xy-pic pdf driver: `line' extension support
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyp
df-li.tex" loaded) Xy-pic pdf driver: `rotate' extension support
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xypic\xyp
df-ro.tex" loaded) loaded))
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hy
perref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2019/09/28 v7.00a Hypertext links for LaTeX

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\
hobsub-hyperref.sty"
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\
hobsub-generic.sty"
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)

! Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined.

See the ifluatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1395 }
        %
Incompatible versions of \ifluatex can cause problems,
therefore package loading is aborted.

Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)

! Package ifvtex Error: Name clash, \ifvtex is already defined.

See the ifvtex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1620 }
        %
Incompatible versions of \ifvtex can cause problems,
therefore package loading is aborted.

Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifpdf' (already loaded).
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/07/25 v0.30 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\ke
yval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks24
)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifx
etex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\au
xhook.sty"
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kv
options.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen139
\Hy@linkcounter=\count100
\Hy@pagecounter=\count101

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd
1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2019/09/28 v7.00a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count102
! Extra \fi.
l.2936 \fi

I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.


("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/00miktex\hy
perref.cfg"
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4414.

("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pu
enc.def"
File: puenc.def 2019/09/28 v7.00a Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `pdfusetitle' set `true' on input line 4414.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `true' on input line 4414.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksnumbered' set `false' on input line 441
4.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksopen' set `false' on input line 4414.
Package hyperref Info: Option `breaklinks' set `false' on input line 4414.
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 4414.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4540.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4545.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4548.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4555.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4560.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4793.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count103
("C:\Users\Charles\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty
"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5152.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen140
\Fld@menulength=\count104
\Field@Width=\dimen141
\Fld@charsize=\dimen142
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6423.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6428.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6431.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6438.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 6441.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6448.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6453.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6493.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6497.
\Hy@abspage=\count105
\c@Item=\count106
\c@Hfootnote=\count107
)
! Undefined control sequence.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...p {hvtexhtm}\ifvtexhtml 
                                                  \ifx \Hy@driver \Hy@temp \...
l.16 \hypersetup
                {
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


Package hyperref Warning: Wrong driver `hpdftex.def';
(hyperref)                VTeX is running in HTML mode.
(hyperref)                Forcing driver `hvtexhtm.def'.

! Extra \else.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...iver \Hy@temp \fi \else 
                                                  \ifx \Hy@driver \Hy@temp \...
l.16 \hypersetup
                {
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.


Package hyperref Warning: Wrong driver `hvtexhtm.def';
(hyperref)                VTeX is not running in HTML mode.
(hyperref)                Using default driver.

! Extra \fi.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...ver \@empty \fi \fi \fi 
                                                  \let \HyOpt@DriverType \lt...
l.16 \hypersetup
                {
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \fi.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...\fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi 
                                                  \ifx \Hy@driver \Hy@defaul...
l.16 \hypersetup
                {
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \fi.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...indo}{color}\fi \fi \fi 
                                                  \else \def \HyOpt@DriverTy...
l.16 \hypersetup
                {
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \else.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...color}\fi \fi \fi \else 
                                                  \def \HyOpt@DriverType { (...
l.16 \hypersetup
                {
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \fi.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...\HyOpt@CustomDriver \fi 
                                                  \Hy@InfoNoLine {Driver\HyO...
l.16 \hypersetup
                {
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

Package hyperref Info: Driver (custom): .

! LaTeX Error: File `.def' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: def)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.16 \hypersetup
                {
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10729 strings out of 492452
 147762 string characters out of 3116793
 275431 words of memory out of 3000000
 15016 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 5852 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 31i,0n,28p,3272b,37s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

And also additional packages that I put on preamble is as follows:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[margin=3.5cm,headheight=35pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

PS: I already tried adding xypic and xypdf, it didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your TeX installation, specifically, update `oberdiek` bundle you should have

```
\ProvidesPackage{hobsub-generic}[2019/10/27]
```

hobsub was updated at the same time as iftex, to avoid the problem that you show.

Your log shows

```
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
```

So you have a 2016 hobsub despite having an iftex from 2019/10/24

Comment: Thank you!!! I reinstalled oberdiek package and now it compiles! Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @CharlesCarmichael well don't thank me too much as I broke your original:-) (I updated iftex...)

Comment: Same error as above. I updated the oberdiek bundle and the error still persists. Please help

Comment: @AK16 then the update did not succeed, if you have miktex did you update both admin and user?  the current version of hobsub and ifluatex packages do not contain an error message that says `! Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined.` so  if you have that error you have an old version of th epackage in your path, check the log file for exactly which versions of the package were used