# Package ifvtex Error: Name clash, \ifvtex is already defined

Tags: errors, compilation-error

When I compile my document, I get the error

```
Package ifvtex Error: Name clash, \ifvtex is already defined.
```

I followed what was suggested in these 2 threads:
[Link 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515598/package-ifluatex-error-name-clash-ifluatex-is-already-defined)
[Link 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515263/xymatrix-figures-cause-compilation-error)

But I still get the same error. The suggestion in both threads comes down to updating the MikTeX installation, which I have done using the GUI. There are no possible updates anymore.

Anyone know what I can do?

Please see the log file below

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.12.17)  17 DEC 2019 14:48
entering extended mode
**./myQE.tex
(myQE.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(Thesis.cls
Document Class: Thesis 2007/22/02 v1.0 LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\bk12.clo"
File: bk12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/setspace\setspace.sty"
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty"
Package: fancyhdr 2019/01/31 v3.10 Extensive control of page headers and footer
s
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip43
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip44
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip45
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip46
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip47
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip48
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip49
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip50
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip51
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip52

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen103
))
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count88
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count89
\leftroot@=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count91
\DOTSCASE@=\count92
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count93
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count94
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count95
\dspbrk@lvl=\count96
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count97
\column@=\count98
\maxfields@=\count99
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip53
\multlinetaggap=\skip54
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amscd.sty"
Package: amscd 2017/04/14 v2.1 AMS Commutative Diagrams
\athelp@=\toks19
\minaw@=\dimen112
\bigaw@=\dimen113
\minCDarrowwidth=\dimen114
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amscls\amsthm.sty"
Package: amsthm 2017/10/31 v2.20.4
\thm@style=\toks20
\thm@bodyfont=\toks21
\thm@headfont=\toks22
\thm@notefont=\toks23
\thm@headpunct=\toks24
\thm@preskip=\skip55
\thm@postskip=\skip56
\thm@headsep=\skip57
\dth@everypar=\toks25
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\xspace.sty"
Package: xspace 2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
)
\c@expl=\count100
\c@thm=\count101
\c@lem=\count102
\c@prop=\count103
\c@defn=\count104
\c@assum=\count105
\c@rem=\count106

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/caption\caption.sty"
Package: caption 2018/05/01 v3.3-147 Customizing captions (AR)

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/caption\caption3.sty"
Package: caption3 2018/05/27 v1.8a caption3 kernel (AR)
Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 64.

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks26
)
\captionmargin=\dimen115
\captionmargin@=\dimen116
\captionwidth=\dimen117
\caption@tempdima=\dimen118
\caption@indent=\dimen119
\caption@parindent=\dimen120
\caption@hangindent=\dimen121
)
\c@ContinuedFloat=\count107
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen122
\Gin@req@width=\dimen123
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\epstopdf.sty"
Package: epstopdf 2016/05/15 v2.6 Conversion with epstopdf on the fly (HO)

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)))
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
))
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/booktabs\booktabs.sty"
Package: booktabs 2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen124
\lightrulewidth=\dimen125
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen126
\belowrulesep=\dimen127
\belowbottomsep=\dimen128
\aboverulesep=\dimen129
\abovetopsep=\dimen130
\cmidrulesep=\dimen131
\cmidrulekern=\dimen132
\defaultaddspace=\dimen133
\@cmidla=\count108
\@cmidlb=\count109
\@aboverulesep=\dimen134
\@belowrulesep=\dimen135
\@thisruleclass=\count110
\@lastruleclass=\count111
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen136
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\rotating.sty"
Package: rotating 2016/08/11 v2.16d rotated objects in LaTeX

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\c@r@tfl@t=\count112
\rotFPtop=\skip58
\rotFPbot=\skip59
\rot@float@box=\box28
\rot@mess@toks=\toks27
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/listings\listings.sty"
\lst@mode=\count113
\lst@gtempboxa=\box29
\lst@token=\toks28
\lst@length=\count114
\lst@currlwidth=\dimen137
\lst@column=\count115
\lst@pos=\count116
\lst@lostspace=\dimen138
\lst@width=\dimen139
\lst@newlines=\count117
\lst@lineno=\count118
\lst@maxwidth=\dimen140

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/listings\lstmisc.sty"
File: lstmisc.sty 2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
\c@lstnumber=\count119
\lst@skipnumbers=\count120
\lst@framebox=\box30
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/listings\listings.cfg"
File: listings.cfg 2015/06/04 1.6 listings configuration
))
Package: listings 2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)

(Styles/lstpatch.sty

***
*** This is a patch for listings 1.3, but you're using
*** version 1.6.
***
 *** Patch file not loaded.
***

) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hobsub\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2019-11-14
hobsub not currently supported, see hobsub.dtx to extract original code

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)


! Package ifvtex Error: Name clash, \ifvtex is already defined.

See the ifvtex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.170     }
           %
Incompatible versions of \ifvtex can cause problems,
therefore package loading is aborted.

) ("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\pdfescape.sty"
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\hycolor.sty"
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\xcolor-patch.sty"
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\hopatch.sty"
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
)))
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\letltxmacro.sty"
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
))
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\auxhook.sty"
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\@linkdim=\dimen141
\Hy@linkcounter=\count121
\Hy@pagecounter=\count122

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def"
File: pd1enc.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\intcalc.sty"
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count123

! Extra \fi.
l.2933 \fi

I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/00miktex\hyperref.cfg"
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `true' on input line 4383.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksopen' set `true' on input line 4383.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksnumbered' set `true' on input line 4383
.
Package hyperref Info: Option `hypertexnames' set `true' on input line 4383.
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 4383.
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4383.

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def"
File: puenc.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `breaklinks' set `true' on input line 4383.
Package hyperref Info: Option `plainpages' set `false' on input line 4383.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4509.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4514.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4517.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4524.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4529.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4762.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count124

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty"
\Urlmuskip=\muskip11
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5115.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen142

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\bitset.sty"
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\bigintcalc.sty"
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count125
\Field@Width=\dimen143
\Fld@charsize=\dimen144
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6369.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6374.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6377.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6384.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 6387.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6394.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6439.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6443.

("C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\atbegshi.sty"
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
)
\Hy@abspage=\count126
\c@Item=\count127
\c@Hfootnote=\count128
)
! Extra \fi.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...ver \@empty \fi \fi \fi 
                                                  \let \HyOpt@DriverType \lt...
l.168 \newcommand
                 *{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \fi.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...\fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi 
                                                  \ifx \Hy@driver \Hy@defaul...
l.168 \newcommand
                 *{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \fi.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...indo}{color}\fi \fi \fi 
                                                  \else \def \HyOpt@DriverTy...
l.168 \newcommand
                 *{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \else.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...color}\fi \fi \fi \else 
                                                  \def \HyOpt@DriverType { (...
l.168 \newcommand
                 *{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

! Extra \fi.
\Hy@AtEndOfPackageHook ...\HyOpt@CustomDriver \fi 
                                                  \Hy@InfoNoLine {Driver\HyO...
l.168 \newcommand
                 *{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

Package hyperref Info: Driver (custom): .

! LaTeX Error: File `.def' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: def)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.168 \newcommand
                 *{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11010 strings out of 493235
 158197 string characters out of 3132710
 227981 words of memory out of 3000000
 14477 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3938 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 49i,0n,45p,322b,219s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: You have two pathes with miktex files `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9` and `C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9` and their versions differ. No idea how you managed this but you will have to sort this out.

Comment: Me neither. I removed one, but now I think I messed up MikTeX's installation. I will perform a clean install once MikTeX's servers are back up (they seem to be down atm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell for sure if the problem was what Ulrike Fischer pointed out, which was having 2 MikTeX installations (one in Program Files and another in Program Files (x86)), but once I removed one and performed a clean installation of MikTeX, it worked again.